# RSpec Model Validation failing but works fine in Rails Console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2, factory-bot

I have been really stuck on this problem. My validation for my model fails (like it should) when I'm testing it out in rails console, but my rspec example fails because it validates anyway (which it shouldn't).  What am I missing here or where should I start looking?

Thanks,
Ivan

See below:

```
    ivan:~/Development/ruby/IvanEnviromanRefinery [git:master+]  → bundle exec rspec ../refinerycms-link/
    .............................F.

    Failures:

      1) BlogPost bookmark links must have a link url if it is a link
         Failure/Error: Factory.build(:post,
           expected valid? to return false, got true
         # /Users/ivan/Development/ruby/refinerycms-link/spec/models/blog_post_spec.rb:197:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

    Finished in 6.56 seconds
    31 examples, 1 failure

    Failed examples:

    rspec /Users/ivan/Development/ruby/refinerycms-link/spec/models/blog_post_spec.rb:196 # BlogPost bookmark links must have a link url if it is a link


    ivan:~/Development/ruby/IvanEnviromanRefinery [git:master+]  → rails console
    Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.9)
    ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > b = BlogPost.new
     => #<BlogPost id: nil, title: nil, body: nil, draft: nil, published_at: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, user_id: nil, cached_slug: nil, custom_url: nil, link_url: nil, is_link: nil, custom_teaser: nil> 
    ruby-1.9.2-p180 :002 > b.title=' 2011-06-24 8:34 '
     => " 2011-06-24 8:34 " 
    ruby-1.9.2-p180 :003 > b.body='goo'
     => "goo" 
    ruby-1.9.2-p180 :004 > b.is_link = true
     => true 
    ruby-1.9.2-p180 :005 > b.valid?
     => false
    ruby-1.9.2-p180 :007 > b.save
     => false 
    ruby-1.9.2-p180 :008 > b.errors
     => {:link_url=>["must have a link_url if is_link is true"]} 
    ruby-1.9.2-p180 :009 > 


    require 'spec_helper'
    Dir[File.expand_path('../../../features/support/factories/*.rb', __FILE__)].each{|factory| require factory}

    describe BlogPost do
      let(:blog_post ) { Factory :post }

      ...

        describe "bookmark links" do
          it "may have a bookmark link" do
           Factory.build(:post,
                        :title => "a link",
                        :body => "link text",
                        :is_link => true,
                        :link_url => "http://example.com").should be_valid
           end
          it "must have a link url if it is a link" do
            Factory.build(:post,
                                 :title => "a link",
                                 :body => "link text",
                                 :is_link => true).should_not be_valid
          end     
        end
    end
```

Comment: what do you have in your model?

Comment: I actually just got it working by using .should be_invalid instead, but I have no idea why. Here's a gist with the model: https://gist.github.com/1046125

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you certain that in your second expectation the link_url isnt set somehow? Try outputting the value and check the logs

```
it "must have a link url if it is a link" do
  post = Factory.build(:post,
   :title => "a link",
   :body => "link text",
   :is_link => true)
  Rails.logger.info "Post link: #{post.link_url}"
  post.should_not be_valid
end
```

Comment: Yes, link_url is not set, it's nil. 

I tried adding in puts and awesome_print statements to inspect values. even got rid of the factory and created a model. for some reason when I'm in rspec it things .valid? is true!

Comment: it's now working by using   .should be_invalid. For some reason that works instead of .should_not be_valid

Comment: and now it's working the original way. perhaps restarting spork did the trick. borked by spork!

Comment: @Ivanoats ... I was running in very weird issue ... things working in console, not in Rspec .... just needed to restart spork! ...